# Bring website online with domain without adding the port

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, subdomain, docker-compose

I come to you because currently I have a website that is hosted on my web server. But on this server I have several websites hosted on it. So to access it you have to put a port number. Until then it's normal. Each site has a domain name. What I would like is that we can access these websites without the need to add to the end of the domain name the example port test.fr:1000 And that the domain name is just display without the port number. test.fr

In configuration, I have an Apache server. Thank you for your help Kind regards Erwan

Comment: apache should let you do that - read the "Apache Virtual Host" documentation for how that works

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the default ports for [HTTP (port 80)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738#section-3.3) and respectively for [HTTPS (port 443)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2818#section-2.3).

The default ports can be found in [/etc/services file](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/services.5.html) on a Linux/UNIX server or in [RFC-1700](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1700)

Comment: Precisely I tried to put port 80, but it does not work. It puts me ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. Whereas when I put port 1000 for example and well it works

Comment: How do you configure docker and the apacke listener? Share in the question the output of `ss -tlnp` and filter with `grep` for your apache process.